# Github API (V3) Contents sha key

Tags: api, github

I'm sorry if this is obvious, but I can't figure out what this key is!

```
{
  "type": "file",
  "encoding": "base64",
  "size": 5362,
  "name": "README.md",
  "path": "README.md",
  "content": "encoded content ...",
  "sha": "3d21ec53a331a6f037a91c368710b99387d012c1", <<THIS KEY>>
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octokit/octokit.rb/contents/README.md",
  "git_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octokit/octokit.rb/git/blobs/3d21ec53a331a6f037a91c368710b99387d012c1",
  "html_url": "https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb/blob/master/README.md",
  "download_url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/octokit/octokit.rb/master/README.md",
  "_links": {
    "git": "https://api.github.com/repos/octokit/octokit.rb/git/blobs/3d21ec53a331a6f037a91c368710b99387d012c1",
    "self": "https://api.github.com/repos/octokit/octokit.rb/contents/README.md",
    "html": "https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb/blob/master/README.md"
  }
}
```

I marked the key with <> to help.

https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-contents

Comment: may this be the commit hash ?

Comment: Otherwise it might be a [sha algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Hash_Algorithm) for verification purpose.

Comment: It is not a commit hash. This JSON represents a *blob*, not a commit. See below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the hash for the given *blob*, which is how Git represents files internally. It's common knowledge that commits have hashes, but [so do all other Git objects](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects):

> Git is a content-addressable filesystem. Great. What does that mean? It means that at the core of Git is a simple key-value data store. You can insert any kind of content into it, and it will give you back a key that you can use to retrieve the content again at any time.

Trees, commits, and tags are the other types of Git objects.

To generate the hash of a file manually you can use the [`hash-object` plumbing command](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-hash-object):

```
$ git hash-object README.md
3d21ec53a331a6f037a91c368710b99387d012c1
```

Any<sup>1</sup> change to the file's content will change the hash, but it is not dependent on the file's name, or permissions.

<sup>1</sup>As with all cryptographic hashes, duplicate hashes are possible but extremely unlikely.

Comment: Is there any way to generate the key with just the file downloaded?

Can I use this to tell if someone changed a file?

Comment: @KingofGamesYami, please see my updated answer. I'm not sure that this is the best way to tell if someone changed a file, but it might do what you want.

Comment: What I'm doing is creating an installer for a limited environment (ComputerCraft using LuaJ). I can execute GET and POST requests, but not much else.

This part is of interest to me because I may want to add an update parameter to my installer, so that it downloads only what hasn't changed.

Another question:  Will the sha key of a folder change if a file changed that is stored inside it?  This could potentially decrease the number of GET requests I have to send to github.

Comment: @KingofGamesYami, tree hashes will change when their contents do, but trees aren't exactly analogous to directories, and `hash-object` doesn't work directly with directories.

Comment: @KingofGamesYami, in general Stack Overflow is designed for one question per Question. Please don't ask multiple questions at once, especially in comments.